# cvResize identifier is undefined

Tags: opencv

All my OpenCV functions are working perfectly fine. But `cvResize()` is not found by the compiler. I guess this function is not installed during installation. 
The following program tells me the error that cvResize identifier is undefined

Is it possible to download this function separately and use it? How?

```c
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    // Create an IplImage object *image 
    IplImage *source = cvLoadImage( argv[1]);
    // Here we retrieve a percentage value to a integer
    int percent = atoi(argv[3]);

    // declare a destination IplImage object with correct size, depth and channels
      IplImage *destination = cvCreateImage
    ( cvSize((int)((source->width*percent)/100) , (int)((source->height*percent)/100) ), source->depth, source->nChannels );

    //use cvResize to resize source to a destination image
    cvResize(source, destination);

    // save image with a name supplied with a second argument
      cvSaveImage( argv[2], destination );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing an include:

```c
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the error by

```
#import <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem when updating to OpenCV latest version on my iOS App. :)